# Pyparsing: access outer ParseResults in parseaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

```
from pyparsing import *
class AParseActionHolder(object):
    def __call__(self, string, index, t):
        f(info_from_outer_parse_results,t[0])
expr = operatorPrecedence( Word(nums),[
         (Literal('A'), 1, opAssoc.RIGHT,AParseActionHolder()),
         (Literal('B'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
         (Literal('C'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT)])
print(expr.parseString("3B1C2BA1")[0])#[['3','B','1'],'C',['2','B',"nested in B and C"]]
print(expr.parseString("A1B3")[0])#["nested in B", 'B', '3']
print(expr.parseString("A(1B3)")[0])#["not nested", ['1', 'B', '3']]
```

How can I access info from outer parsing result in which the argument of parseaction is nested?
Can I do it with parseaction? If not is there some other Pyparsing tool for it or I should define recursive function that takes pyparsing.ParseResults as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to access the outer results - in your case, because they haven't even been parsed yet at the time the inner results are being parsed!

You will probably have to write a recursive function that works on the fully parsed tree that you get back from `parseString`. As you walk the tree, keep track of your path, and when you find an "A" element, replace it with the path.

It may be difficult to work with the returned `ParseResults` directly, so you may want to get the tree by calling `asList()` on the returned results:

```
tree = expr.parseString("whatever").asList()
```